# How to add a new property to each object in a list in terraform?

Tags: terraform

```
 new_list = [for item in list : {...item, newProp = XYZ}]
```

I assumed, javascript object deconstructor works in tf files, but does it? I don't want to list all the existing properties of `item` above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the merge function to add a new property to each object in a list without having to explicitly list all the existing properties. example below:

```
new_list = [for item in list : merge(item, {newProp = "XYZ"})]
```